# Theming a page template for specific content in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Hi everyone i am new in Drupal 7 and i have tried many options bt i can not get specific result that i wanted. I have a Drupal site which have four template files
+ page.tpl.php
+ page--front.tpl.php
+ page--forum.tpl.php
+ page--blogs.tpl.php

So the page.tpl.php is used as an inner page where forum is being showed and other staffs are showed but i want a page template different than page.tpl.php file where blogs get visible.

Now the problem is that blog urls are like this http://localhost/drupal/content/test-blog
http://localhost/drupal/content/blog-one

Now all the pages are redirecting to page.tpl.php file whereas i want it to be redirect to page--blogs.tpl.php page.

I tried this and it works but i know this is not correct solution.

`function lars_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {

```
 $alias = drupal_get_path_alias(arg(0) . '/' . arg(1));

 $content_path = substr($alias, 0,7);

 if($content_path == 'content'){
 $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  'page__blogs';}`
```

I want to know what will be the correct solution for this  kind of problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on template.php, you are on the right track.

> The only thing "page" knows about are the path arguments. Nothing is in there to pick-up on node types. You need to help it out.

Please follow https://www.drupal.org/node/1142800#comment-4433994